# How to coalesce columns that have NA using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, multiple-columns, na, coalesce

I am looking to combine rows that have NA across multiple columns using dplyr. I have not been able to find a way around this problem. I am still new to R, so apologies in advance.

I want to change this example data frame:

```
# Groups:   RID, FlankerCongruence, NoiseLevel 
     RID FlankerCongruence TrialStim.ACC NoiseLevel TrialStim.RT  
   <int> <chr>                     <int>      <int>        <int> 
 1   101 Congruent                     1          0           NA    
 2   101 Congruent                     1          0           NA     
 3   101 Congruent                     1          0           NA    
 4   101 Congruent                    NA          0          678   
 5   101 Congruent                    NA          0          909   
 6   101 Congruent                    NA          0          928
```

into something that looks like this:

```
 # Groups:   RID, FlankerCongruence, NoiseLevel 
    RID FlankerCongruence TrialStim.ACC NoiseLevel TrialStim.RT  
   <int> <chr>                     <int>      <int>        <int> 
 1   101 Congruent                     1          0          678     
 2   101 Congruent                     1          0          909     
 3   101 Congruent                     1          0          928
```

I first tried using this:

```
coalesce_by_column <- function(noMeancombinedNoiseTable.data) {
  return(dplyr::coalesce(!!! as.list(noMeancombinedNoiseTable.data)))
}

noMeancombinedNoiseTable.data <- noMeancombinedNoiseTable.data %>%
  group_by(RID, FlankerCongruence, NoiseLevel) %>% 
  arrange(RID, FlankerCongruence, NoiseLevel) %>%
  summarise_all(coalesce_by_column)
```

But that summarized columns like this:

```
    RID FlankerCongruence NoiseLevel TrialStim.ACC TrialStim.RT 
   <int> <chr>                  <int>         <int>        <int> 
 1   101 Congruent                  0             1          678
```

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2):

We could group by the columns, realign the NAs in other columns and keep the rows with at least one non-NA value

```
library(dplyr)
noMeancombinedNoiseTable.data %>%
  group_by(RID, FlankerCongruence, NoiseLevel) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ .x[order(!is.na(.x))])) %>%
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ !is.na(.x))) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
    RID FlankerCongruence TrialStim.ACC NoiseLevel TrialStim.RT
  <int> <chr>                     <int>      <int>        <int>
1   101 Congruent                     1          0          678
2   101 Congruent                     1          0          909
3   101 Congruent                     1          0          928
```

#### data

```
noMeancombinedNoiseTable.data <- structure(list(RID = c(101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L), FlankerCongruence = c("Congruent", 
"Congruent", "Congruent", "Congruent", "Congruent", "Congruent"
), TrialStim.ACC = c(1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA), NoiseLevel = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), TrialStim.RT = c(NA, NA, NA, 678L, 909L, 
928L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"))
```